# Error loading cr2 with edsdk

Tags: c++, error-code, edsdk

I am trying to read cr2 images using canon sdk (canon_edsdk-2.12).

I seem to be loading the dll correctly, but when I try to get the actual image, I get an error.

I tried to run the sample program to see how that is different than mine, but the same thing happens.

Trying to look for the issue on the web, I found the actual source code of the sample: http://read.pudn.com/downloads107/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/440409/RAWDevelop/RAWDevelopDlg.cpp__.htm

My error, on the given source, is in the `void CRAWDevelopDlg::LoadImage()` function -

```
err = EdsGetImage( m_ImageRef , source , kEdsTargetImageType_RGB , rect , size , DstStreamRef );   
if( err == EDS_ERR_OK ) {...}
else   
{   
   AfxMessageBox("The error occurred with the EdsGetImage function.");   
}
```

The above (on line 481 on the page) is the same method that I use, and i get the same error - with error code 35 (instead of 0).

The error seems to be

```
#define EDS_ERR_FILE_OPEN_ERROR                          0x00000023L
```

So... could there be something wrong with the files ? I experimented with files taken by different versions, including the newest cameras... The files open in Photoshop... And the demo does show header information, as it gives the error. So it can see something.

Am I missing anything ?

All the required dll's used are on the system path...

Thank you.

Comment: 35 decimal is 0x23 not 0x21. If it is indeed 35 you are getting EDS_ERR_FILE_OPEN_ERROR = 0x23L;

Comment: Right... how stupid of me. Thank you. The files that I tried it on should be valid files though, I can open them with Photoshop... I experimented with cr2 files taken with different cameras.  (Will update the post)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, still, might help someone:

To open a raw file with the SDK you need to call these functions (you should check for errors, of course):

```
EdsStreamRef stream = NULL;
EdsImageRef imgRef = NULL;
EdsCreateFileStream("filename", kEdsFile_OpenExisting, kEdsAccess_Read, &stream);
EdsCreateImageRef(stream, &imgRef);
EdsRelease(stream);
```

Then you can set and get properties with the imgRef.

To save the image as jpg/tiff/RGB image use EdsSaveImage function.